# Question about free variables in mathematical logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

So the concept is from Herbert.B.enderton, A mathematical introduction to Logic.

Now consider the following expression:

1.) $\forall v_2 (Av_2 \rightarrow\ Bv_2)$

2.)$(\forall v_1Av_1 \rightarrow\ Bv_1)$

The books says 1.) is a sentence, meaning no variable occurs freely. But 2.) is not, as $v_1$ occurs freely.

But why is that ? I would really like an explanation on this. Thank you

Comment: Why is what, exactly? It follows from the very definition of *statement* that 2.) isn't one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2, the *scope* of the quantifier $\forall v_1$ is only the $Av_1$ part, hence the $v_1$ in $Bv_1$ is free, making 2 not a sentence.

In 1, the *parentheses* are used to make the scope of the quantifier $\forall v_2$ to be all of $Av_2 \rightarrow Bv_2$, so there are no free variables there.

Comment: Can I go into abit more detail and interpret it like this:  For 1.), I can "distribute" the $\forall$ quantifier to both sides of the implication, and see that $v_1$ does not occur freely on either side. But for 2.), the $v_1$ is free on the right as per your explanation